# Azure DevOps SendMail Rest API returns 204 but doesn't send an email

Tags: azure, api, email, azure-devops, tfs

I am trying to use the following SendMail Azure DevOps Rest API route to send out e-mails in PowerShell:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/send-mail/send-mail?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#emailrecipients

This is the JSON body I am using for this request:

```
{
            "message" : {
            "body": "<p>Test Email</p>",
            "to" : {
                "tfIds" : ["mytfsid here"]
             },
            "cc" : {},
            "replyTo" : {},
            "inReplyTo" : "",          
            "subject" : "test"
            },
            "projectId" : "my project id here"
}
```

Postman shows me my request passes with 204; however, I am not receiving any e-mails. I'm at a loss. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or why the e-mail would fail to deliver?

Thanks in advance.

```
What I've tried: 

- Tried using the tfId of a colleague; still no e-mail received
- Tried using emailAddresses instead within the "to" block; still does not work.
- Tried using emailAddresses AND tfIds within the "to" block; still does not work.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure the notification works well, otherwise you have to troubleshoot the notification issue first. See [Why am I not receiving notification emails?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/troubleshoot-not-getting-email?view=azure-devops)

If the notification works well, then please try below PowerShell script to send email for the selected work items: (works for me)

```
Param(
   [string]$orgname = "{org-name}",
   [string]$project = "{project-name}",
   [string]$sendmailto = "xxx@xxx.com",
   [string]$mysubject = "Test-Subject",
   [string]$mailbody = "Body test",
   [string]$witids = "1536,1537",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get the tfsid
$userentitlementurl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$orgname/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $userentitlementurl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

#Filter by sendmailto
$tfsid = ($response.value| where {$_.user.mailAddress -eq $sendmailto}).id
#Create Jason body
function CreateJsonBody
{
    $value = @"
        {
            "message": "{\"to\":{\"tfIds\":[\"$tfsid\"],\"emailAddresses\":[],\"unresolvedEntityIds\":[]},\"subject\":\"$mysubject\",\"body\":\"$mailbody\",\"cc\":{\"tfids\":[\"$tfsid\"]},\"replyTo\":{\"tfids\":[\"$tfsid\"]}}",
            "ids": [
                $witids
            ],
            "fields": [
                "System.Id",
                "System.Title",
                "System.AssignedTo",
                "System.State",
                "System.AreaPath",
                "System.Tags",
                "System.CommentCount"
            ],
            "format": 1
        }
"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$baseurl = "https://dev.azure.com/$orgname/$project/_api/_wit/sendMail?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

#Send mail
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseurl -Method POST -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I was missing the ids parameter for work item ids. Appreciate the help.