# Use the Azure DevOps WorkItemTracking sendmail returns 411

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am getting the following error when I try to curl Azure´s [SendMail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/send-mail/send-mail?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) endpoint. The documentation is not really helpful. What am I doing wrong?

```
endpoint=https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/_apis/wit/sendmail?api-version=7.1-preview.1
body='{
"message": {
"body": "Test Body",
"cc": {},
"to": {
"tfsIds": ["my-tfsIds-id"]
},
"replyTo": {},
"subject": "Test Subject"
},
projectId:"my-project-id"
}'

curl -X POST "$endpoint" --data "$body" -H "Authorization: Basic $pat" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -vL
```

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

PS: I also get a redirect and I don´t really understand why either but I guess it´s the sign in authority?

```
* Connection #0 to host dev.azure.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://xxxxx.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=dev.azure.com&reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.azure.com%2FMYORG%2FMYPRODJECT%2F_apis%2Fwit%2Fsendmail%3Fapi-version%3D7.1-preview.1&redirect=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
* Switch from POST to GET
*   Trying xx.xxx.xx.xx:443...
* Connected to xxxxx.vssps.visualstudio.com (xx.xxx.xx.xx:443) port 443 (#1)
```

---

**Update**

By including the `Content-Length` header it now returns a 503..

> Sorry! Our services aren't available right now.
>
> We're working to restore all services as quickly as possible. Please
> check back soon.
>
> To see the latest status on our services, please visit our support
> page.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below PowerShell script to invoke `POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/sendmail?api-version=7.1-preview.1` and getting the email as expected.

```
$myorg="organization_name"
$myproject="project_name"
$pat="Base64 converted PAT"
$endpoint="https://dev.azure.com/$myorg/$myproject/_apis/wit/sendmail?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
$body='{
    "ids": [work item id],
    "message": {
        "body": "Test Body",
        "cc": {},
        "to": {
            "tfIds": ["your tfId"]
        },
        "replyTo": {},
        "subject": "Test Subject"
    }
}'

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $endpoint -Method POST -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $pat")} -ContentType "application/json"
```

Please add  **`ids`** for work item ids and correct **`tfIds`** in your request body.

**Email-**

[image]

***References:-***
[Azure DevOps SendMail Rest API returns 204 but doesn't send an email - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74198174/azure-devops-sendmail-rest-api-returns-204-but-doesnt-send-an-email)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I think that my org does not allow to use the API...

Comment: @Bennimi what error you are getting? Please check if you have granted [this](https://i.imgur.com/acknC4K.png) role to the PAT

Comment: It´s strange, I need to follow a redirect otherwise nothing happens, then I have to include the content length, otherwise I get the mentioned 411. With both included I now get a service time-out. I don´t think the issue is with the content body. (I updated my answer).

Comment: Have you tried without content length?

Comment: yes, the initial error from this question was without this header

Comment: are you using my powershell script and have you provided access to your pat?

Comment: I use base since I dont have psh, but what difference does it make? Yes, I use my pat, what do you mean by *provided access to my pat*?

Comment: @Bennimi check https://i.imgur.com/acknC4K.png. please use my script. In your case message body and `curl -X POST "$endpoint" --data "$body" -H "Authorization: Basic $pat" -H "Content-Type: application/json"` is not correct

Comment: it does not work either. I have a token with full scope from within a devops pipeline but now I get ` Azure DevOps Services | Sign In` and that´s it

Comment: can you share the screenshot, how you are running the script?

Comment: see https://ibb.co/fMBHrfc

Comment: Please verify if you are using correct organization_Name, Project_Name, PAT

Comment: I wish that were the issue.

Comment: @Bennimi After using my script with all the correct data, you are not getting the result? If not, I would suggest you to check with the product team. Above script works for me

Comment: No it does not work either. Yes will do, thanks for your help!

Comment: what error you are getting currently?

Comment: getting a redirect to a sign in page and that´s it.

Comment: Have you tried you sign in? If yes, what's the result you are getting?

Comment: nothing. I am in contact with my product team to see whether they restrict the access to the API in general.